# EJB2 - $Proxy0 cannot be cast to com.TestEJB.TestEJBInterfaceRemote error

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0, ejb-2.x

I am trying to build a simpmle Hello world type EJB 2.1 application. The intended runtime for this application is supposed to be Jboss 5.1.0. 
Here is the code i have written.

EJB Configuration file:

ejb/TestEJBInterfaceBean
                com.TestEJB.TestEJBInterfaceHome
                com.TestEJB.TestEJBInterfaceRemote
                com.TestEJB.TestEJBInterfaceBean
                Stateless
                Container

Home interface:

```
import javax.ejb.EJBHome;

public interface TestEJBInterfaceHome extends EJBHome {
    public TestEJBInterfaceRemote create() throws java.rmi.RemoteException,
            javax.ejb.CreateException;
}

Remote Interface:

import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import javax.ejb.EJBObject;

public interface TestEJBInterfaceRemote extends EJBObject { 

    public String ping(String version) throws RemoteException;
}
```

Bean class:

```
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.util.Date;

import org.jboss.logging.Logger;

public class TestEJBIInterfaceBean extends BaseSessionBean implements TestEJBIInterfaceRemote{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TestEJBIInterfaceBean.class);   


    public String ping(String arg0) throws RemoteException {

        String response = this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " pinged @ " + new Date().getTime();

        log.info(response);
        return response;
    }

    public void ejbActivate() throws EJBException, RemoteException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void ejbPassivate() throws EJBException, RemoteException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void ejbRemove() throws EJBException, RemoteException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void setSessionContext(SessionContext arg0) throws EJBException,
            RemoteException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public EJBHome getEJBHome() throws RemoteException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public Handle getHandle() throws RemoteException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public Object getPrimaryKey() throws RemoteException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public boolean isIdentical(EJBObject arg0) throws RemoteException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    public void remove() throws RemoteException, RemoveException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

The Test Client:

```
public class TestEJBInterfaceClientTest {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Context ctx = new InitialContext();

            TestEJBInterfaceRemote obj = (TestEJBInterfaceRemote)ctx.lookup("ejb/TestEJBInterfaceBean");

            System.out.println(obj.ping("12345"));

        } catch (NamingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}
```

When i run the client i get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy0 cannot be cast to com.TestEJB.TestEJBInterfaceRemote
    at TestEJBInterfaceClientTest.main(TestEJBInterfaceClientTest.java:21)
```

The error seems to suggest that the cast is wrong but i suspect that the casting has nothing to do with the error. (i tried to cast to TestEJBInterfaceHome but i get the same error). My suspisions are actually in the version of the application.

Questions

- Is there any possibility that Jboss is treating this as an EJB3 application? Looking at the configuration file i am not specifying that this is an EJB2.1 so maybe that is causing a problem?
- Is there any way to find out what Type is returned from the `ctx.lookup` call? i tried `getClass().getName`, `getClass().getCanonicalName()` and all i get back is names like `$proxy0, $proxy20` etc.
- Have i missed something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of a pre-EJB-3.0 lookup is the home interface, so try casting to `TestEJBInterfaceHome` instead.  Note that for portability, you need to use [PortableRemoteObject.narrow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/rmi/PortableRemoteObject.html#narrow%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Class%29) on the return value of ctx.lookup before casting to the target interface.

The actual type is a proxy class, so `getClass().getName()` is returning the correct thing.  To determine what interfaces are implemented by the class, use `getClass().getInterfaces()`.